# Rspec and Draper : unitialized constant on class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, draper

On Rails 4 when I execute rspec tests for a decorator I got the following error :

```
/app/spec/decorators/my_decorator_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyDecorator (NameError)
```

I'm surely missing something but I don't know what.

I generate the decorator

```
rails g decorator My
```

A spec/my_decorator_spec.rb file is generated, with the content :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyDecorator do
end
```

Then I test

```
rspec spec/decorators/my_decorator_spec.rb
```

I didn't add anything in application.rb or spec_helper.rb.
The decorator itself works correctly.

**EDIT**

It's weirder than I expected. When I test all rspec files, tests inside my decorator spec file are correctly executed.

It works :

```
rspec spec/
```

It doesn't :

```
rspec spec/decorators
rspec spec/decorators/my_decorator_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the decorator specs being generated with `require 'spec_helper'` rather than `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of the file.  When you run other specs **before** the decorator specs (e.g., the controller specs, when running `rspec spec/`, since c comes before d), then they end up requiring the right file before your decorator specs get run, so all is well.

The solution is to replace the spec_helper requires with rails_helper in your decorator specs:

```
perl -pi -e 's/spec_helper/rails_helper/' spec/decorators/*
```

Once you do that, you should have no problems running `rspec spec/decorators`.

N.B.: [This change](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/commit/03f969c503ea56d0192ad772c540bf805e28e9e9) has been made in the draper repo, but it was made after version 2.1.0 of the gem was released, which is the latest non-pre release of the gem.